# checking if a value is one of many constants

Tags: java

In Python, you can:

```
if error_code in (1213,1205,1317,2006,2013):
    ...
```

How can you concisely do the same kind of check - seeing if an int is one of many choices - in Java?

UPDATE: the solution I adopted:

```
private static final Set<Integer> MySQLRetryCodes = 
    Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Integer>(
         Arrays.asList(
            1205, // lock timeout
            1213, // deadlock
            1317,2006,2013 // variations on losing connection to server
         )));
```

and then later:

```
if(MySQLRetryCodes.contains(sqlError.getErrorCode()) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use HashSet :

```
  if (new HashSet<Integer>
          (Arrays.asList(1213,1205,1317,2006,2013)).contains(error_code)){

       //do something

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The constants would be in a list and you would use the `contains()` method as follows:

```
if (Arrays.asList(1213,1205,1317,2006,2013).contains(error_code)) {
    ...
}
```

The best way is to declare this list as a constant somewhere and use it, as follows:

```
public static final List<Integer> ERROR_CODES = 
    Arrays.asList(1213,1205,1317,2006,2013);

...
if (ERROR_CODES.contains(error_code)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The compiler would automatically determine the type and `<Integer>` is not needed explicitly.

Comment: well I just had to put in <Integer> to keep Eclipse happy.

Answer (score 1):

Writing `ArrayList` for error Codes is really `bad design`. `And populate it just to check whether error code is present is nightmare.`

You should consider replacing your integers with [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

You can define error code as enum and each constant will hold int constant value for error code.

```
enum ErrorCode {
    ERROR_213(213), ERROR_1205(1205), ERROR_1317(1317), ERROR_2006(2006), ERROR_DEFAULT(
            1);

    private int errorcode;

    private ErrorCode(int errorcode) {
        this.errorcode = errorcode;
    }

    public static ErrorCode valueOf(int errorcode) {

        for (ErrorCode error : ErrorCode.values()) {
            if (error.getErrorCode() == errorcode)
                return error;
        }
        return ErrorCode.ERROR_DEFAULT;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorcode;
    }
}
```

Now if you want to convert `int` value at any time to `enum` then you can do following

```
ErrorCode errorcode = ErrorCode.valueOf(213);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add them to an `ArrayList` and use the `contains` method.

```
ArrayList<Integer> errorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        errorList.add(1213);
        errorList.add(1205);
        errorList.add(1317);
    if(errorList.contains(error_code)))
       {
         //code
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question now, and reading the answers to this question, I come to the next solution in Java 9 times:

```
private static int CODE_IMAGE = 0;
private static int CODE_FILE  = 5;
private static final Set<Integer> CurrentCloudItemTypes = Set.of(CODE_IMAGE, CODE_FILE);
```

And later:

```
  protected boolean hasCorrectType(CloudImage image) {
    return CurrentCloudItemTypes.contains(image.getType());
  }
```

Thank you for your ideas, they were helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the return value of:

```
Arrays.asList(1213, 1205, 1317, 2006, 2013).contains(error_code)
```

or if you have the [Apache Commons Lang library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) you better to use the return value of this:

```
ArrayUtils.contains(USE_CASE_1, error_code)
```

Where the `USE_CASE_1` is defined as a constant array:

```
private static final int[] USE_CASE_1 = {1213, 1205, 1317, 2006, 2013};
```

This is the most simple and quite efficient equivalent of your Python code above, where you do **a non-frequent checks** of the `error_code` variable over **a small set** of specified values. You really don't need to create a new Set each time you want to do this check, since it's an inefficient waste of resources. Making a small Set of check values has sense only if it's a static final field (i.e. constant) and only in case of **very frequent checks**.

Another solution is using a switch statement like that:

```
switch (error_code) {
    case 1213:
    case 1205:
    case 1317:
    case 2006:
    case 2013: {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It's not elegant but it's the most efficient even for **very frequent checks** over **a small set** of specified values. In this case it's even more efficient than constant Set.